# Writing Junits test class for a DoubleClickListener

Tags: junit, swt

I need to write a Junit test class for my `DoubleClickImplementation` class. Here is the code :

DoubleClickImplementation.java

```
public class DoubleClickImplementation implements IDoubleClickListener {
private TreeViewer treeViewer;
public DoubleClickImplementation(TreeViewer viewer) {
this.treeViewer = viewer;
}
/**
* Expands and Collapses the tree items.
* 
* @param event
* 
*/
@Override
public void doubleClick(DoubleClickEvent event) {
IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) treeViewer.getSelection();
if (selection == null || selection.isEmpty()) {
return;
}
Object item = selection.getFirstElement();
ITreeContentProvider provider = (ITreeContentProvider) treeViewer.getContentProvider();
if (!provider.hasChildren(item)) {
return;
}
if (treeViewer.getExpandedState(item)) {
treeViewer.collapseToLevel(item, AbstractTreeViewer.ALL_LEVELS);
} else {
treeViewer.expandToLevel(item, 1);
}
}
}
```

And this is how I instantiate `DoubleClickImplementation` class from another class named `RepoView`

```
private TreeViewer browseTreeViewer;
private DoubleClickImplementation doubleClickExpansionListener;
doubleClickExpansionListener = new DoubleClickImplementation(browseTreeViewer);
browseTreeViewer.addDoubleClickListener(doubleClickExpansionListener);
```

Please give me a Junit test class for the above mentioned `DoubleClickImplementation` class's `doubleClick()` method. I'm completely new to JUnits.

Comment: Asking for code is off topic for Stack Overflow see [What topics can I ask about](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Ok I went through the topics that could be asked. Can u suggest on how to write a Junit test class for the doubleClick(DoubleClickEvent event) method or show me a demo so that I could implement it.

Comment: I now realize that this was a stupid question from me. I was a newbie in Junits and had panicked because of my Project Deadlines, I regret the inconvenience caused with such a nonsensical question. Apologies from my end. Can this question be deleted or should I reformulate it better and answer my own question?